# Can't hear any audio in play mode, but can in inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

before everything worked, now even in old projects the sound does not work
what i already tried:

- restart/reinstall Unity
- restarting the computer
- disabling and restarting window audio
- used sounds that worked before

sound works in build

[toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dswot.png)

Comment: Hey @Xomyak Ammiak maybe you accidentally pressed the Mute Audio button in Game view?

Comment: ohh yes i'm an idiot thanks